# how can i plot a bar chart m variable and how cam i extract each column and save it in a list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

----------python

```
        import pandas as pd
        import matplotlib.pyplot as p
        from IPython.display import display
        
        survey =pd.read_csv('Video_Game_Sales.csv')
        l=[]
```

----------m variable sorts and sums the sales per genre
m=survey.groupby('Genre')[['Global_Sales']].sum().sort_values('Global_Sales')

```
        x=survey["Genre"]
```

----------here the error shows 2d array how to extract the columns from array and use it
as x and y axis
df=pd.DataFrame({"Genre":x,"Global_Sales":m})
ax=df.plot.bar(x='Genre',y="Global_Sales",rot=0)
ax.plot()

```
        p.show()
```

---

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Also, test data seem to be missing. Wouldn't `ax = m.plot.bar(rot=0)` create your plot?  (Further, note that using `import matplotlib.pyplot as p` instead of the standard `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is not only confusing, it can easily lead to weird errors when some temporarily variable happens to get the name `p`.)

Comment: no by as plot cant plot directlty cause the variable m has groupedby genre a column and also a 2nd column global_sales in that particular genre so it says error conations scalar quantity to plot

Comment: m=survey.groupby('Genre')[['Global_Sales']].sum().sort_values('Global_Sales')

Comment: want to plot this but it gives an array so either i directly plot this or extract each column store it into a variable and then easily plot it

Comment: So `survey.groupby('Genre')[['Global_Sales']].sum().sort_values('Global_Sales').plot.bar()`?  You seem to make things a lot more complicated than needed.  Note that the result `m` has a column of values and also an "index".

Answer (score 0):

You can directly plot using the dataframe created by the `groupby` sum.

The dataframe `m` looks like (here using test data) this. Note that it contains both a column with the sales and an "index" indicating the genres.

```py
                  Global_Sales
Genre                         
Other                  5434900
Puzzle                 5779272
MMO                    7885381
Sports                 8177998
Simulation            10883251
Action                11022618
Action-adventure      11821294
Role-playing          12010055
Strategy              12874008
Adventure             14073635
```

You can call `m.plot.bar()` to create a bar plot. (Or `m.plot.barh()` for horizontal bars.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some dummy data for testing purposes
genres = ['Action', 'Action-adventure', 'Adventure', 'Puzzle', 'Role-playing',
          'Simulation', 'Strategy', 'Sports', 'MMO', 'Other']
survey = pd.DataFrame({'Genre': np.random.choice(genres, 200),
                       'Global_Sales': np.random.randint(10000, 1000000, 200)})

# create a dataframe with the sums of sales per genre
m = survey.groupby('Genre')[['Global_Sales']].sum().sort_values('Global_Sales')

# plot the dataframe
ax = m.plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(12, 5))
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain') # prevent scientific notation
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot from groupby dataframe]

Comment: i have one more doubt i tried the other way i printed the group by this i sliced the coloumns and stored it in the list separating both the columns and used them as x-axis and y-axis but when i plot them it shows error of self converter unhashable stuff what does that mean

Comment: i am trying to store index that is genre and the values that is sales cause this is a sample data i have over 50 or 100 typing the genre isnt feasible so i am storing them by slicing them and then plotting i m able to slice and store but not able to plot

Comment: here is the code so far

Comment: m=survey.groupby(['Genre'],as_index=False)[['Global_Sales']].sum().sort_values('Global_Sales')
k=survey['Genre']
a=np.array(m)
c1=a[:,[0]]
c2=a[:,[1]]
l=c1.tolist()
r=c2.tolist()

Comment: Note that the comments aren't meant to add code, instead you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71638163/edit) your original question and add (or modify) extra code.  Note that the simplest what you could do, is to draw horizontal bars with the original `m` with a larger figsize, e.g. `ax = m.plot.barh(figsize=(12, 20))`

Comment: For slicing, you could use `m[20:40].plot.bar(rot=0, figsize=(12, 5))`

Comment: i i directly plot m then how do i add value labels cause i dont have x and y cordinates

Comment: and my x cordinate isnt a numeric value

Comment: `ax = m.plot.barh(figsize=(12, 20)); ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.0f'); ax.margins(x=0.15)`